# Changing file path name every five minutes in logstash csv output plugin

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, dynamic, path, logstash-configuration

My requirement is my file name should change every 5 minutes . Currently I am using below configuration to change it every minute. Please tell me some way to change it every 5 minute.

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  csv {
    # elastic field name
    fields =>  ["@timestamp","requestid","ngnix.responsebytes"]
    
    # This is path where we store output.   
    path => "C:/Users/M1056317/ELK/csv/try6/csv-export-%{+YYYY-MM-dd_hh.mm}.csv"
        
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the time format will allow you to do this.

Another way to achieve what you need is to always write to `C:/Users/M1056317/ELK/csv/try6/csv-export.csv` and use [LogRotate](https://serverfault.com/questions/358172/equivalent-of-logrotate-for-windows) (or equivalent) to rotate your logs every five minutes.